# ruby on rails send_file delay with large files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, delay, send

I've been working on a rails server that I can use to access files stored on my drives in my appartment when I am somewhere else. To handle the downloads I have written the following controller:

```
class DownloadController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title = params[:title]
    @name = params[:name]
    @path = '/media/video/'+@title+'/'+@name
    call_to_download(@path)
  end

  def call_to_download(path)
    send_file( path, :x_sendfile=>true )
  end
end
```

This works really good with small files like images and such but when i try to download a videoclip (around 500 MB) it takes around a minute for the download to actually start.
I've looked around for solutions to this problem but came up with nothing, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try reducing the buffer size: `send_file(path, x_sendfile: true, buffer_size: 512)`

Comment: sadly it didn't change anything

Comment: What server do you use? Apache, Thin, nginx, Webbrick?

Comment: I'm fairly new to rails, but as I haven't changed it I'm assuming it is Webbrick (default?)

Answer (score 1):

Webbrick does not support `x_sendfile`. Therefore it has to load the file completely into memory and that split it into chunks (IMO the default is 4K) before starting to respond. Furthermore it blocks the whole webserver while doing that. I am not surprised that this is slow.

I suggest to use a webserver that does support `x_sendfile`, like apache with passenger for example.

BTW Generating the path directly from the users input, might be a security hole. Guess what happens when someone enters the path to your `database.yml` into the `params[:title]` and `params[:name]`...

Comment: Ohh so that's how it works, explains a lot! At least I'm learning, thanks a ton!